# Using Google's ProtoBuf (and a .proto file) to create a Python API Library

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have the .proto file used in the open-source Android API (http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/), and am having some trouble compiling the file to generate the .py.

I'm trying to follow the instructions here, https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial , and am on the steps that are under the header "Compiling Your Protocol Buffers".

I've downloaded the compiler, protoc.exe. The readme says "To install, simply place this binary somewhere in your PATH," which I'm not understanding. I'm messed around with it for a while now, but can't think of how to proceed.

I'm quite the novice programmer, so please tell me if something isn't clear, or if I'm having some sort of fundamental misunderstanding... about anything. I'm on Windows 7 by the way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if protoc.exe is not in the same directory you're calling it from, you need to add it to your PATH environment variable to be accessible from the calling directory when you're in the shell. open up a command shell and execute:

set PATH=%PATH%c:\directory\to\proto\executable;

then change directories over to where your source code is and execute the compilation line as instructed from the google page.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem because it is not written that clear in the README.txt. What they mean is to: 
1. take the protoc.exe and put it in the same folder with the other files of your project.
2. open the cmd to that directory and run: protoc --cpp_out=. myfile.proto 
=> This will create the 2 new files in the folder with the files of your project, and then you can add them normally to your program.

This helped me: http://www.scriptol.com/programming/protocol-buffers-tutorial.php

This is for c++, but I guess it will be something similar for python; I guess you just have to change the command you are using in the cmd :)